# new class from variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've got a problem. I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and on initialization

```
$class = (string)$module->controller.'Controller';
$class = new $class();
$class->startModule($module->title,$request);
```

I get a response from server `FatalErrorException in ModulesController.php line 29:
Class 'FileManagerController' not found`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sI58.png)
but on manual call it works fine

```
$class = new FileManagerController();
$class->startModule($module->title,$request)
```

Plese tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure file that contains `FileManagerController` class exists and included successfully?

Comment: It exists, but how to include dinamicly full code of class? if I use require $class.".php";      it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

First require class and then create instance:

```
$class = (string)$module->controller.'Controller';
require_once $class . '.php';
$class = new $class();
$class->startModule($module->title,$request);
```

Comment: It doesn't help anyway

Comment: Are both files in same directory? @EvgheniiBuainov

Answer (score 0):

I've got solution

```
$class = (string)$module->controller.'Controller';
app('App\Http\Controllers\\'.$class)->startModule($module->title,$request);
```